# ClickHouse CollapsingMergeTree Wrong Results on Bad Insert

Tags: clickhouse

I am using ClickHouse to build a user tag system, where clients can query a bunch of user IDs based on the tag values of one or many tag IDs. The table looks as follows, and it uses the CollapsingMergeTree (CMT) Engine to handle deduplication of real time updates.

```
CREATE TABLE user_table
(
    `tag_id` UInt64,
    `tag_value` Int64,
    `user_id` UInt32,
    `sign` Int8,
    `create_time` DateTime DEFAULT now()
)
ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree(sign)
PARTITION BY tag_id % 200
ORDER BY (tag_id, tag_value, user_id)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

I encounter a rather odd behavior that gives wrong query results. Consider the following sequence of inserts.

```
-- Insert tag value of 1

INSERT INTO user_table (tag_id, tag_value, user_id, sign)
VALUES (999, 1, 100, 1);

-- I want to update tag value from 1 to 2
-- So, I need to insert (999, 1, 100, -1), (999, 1, 2, 1)
-- But, let's say only the 2nd row is inserted while the first row failed.
-- Due to a lack of atomicity, the inserted 2nd row is not rolled back.

INSERT INTO user_table (tag_id, tag_value, user_id, sign)
VALUES (999, 1, 2, 1);

-- Because of failed batch insert, there is a retry mechanism. 
-- This time, both rows are inserted successfully.

INSERT INTO user_table (tag_id, tag_value, user_id, sign)
VALUES (999, 1, 1, -1), (999, 1, 2, 1);

-- Now, I want to delete tag value 1.

INSERT INTO user_table (tag_id, tag_value, user_id, sign)
VALUES (999, 1, 2, -1);

-- This returns the user, which is incorrect!

SELECT user_id FROM user_table
WHERE tag_id = 999 AND tag_value = 2
GROUP BY (tag_id, tag_value, user_id)
HAVING sum(sign) > 0
```

I've done my research, and I am not sure if the atomicity of a batch insert in ClickHouse is guaranteed. If it is not, how can I structure my query or retry mechanism to handle this edge case?

Comment: The statements "I want to update tag value from 1 to 2" and "So, I need to insert (999, 1, 100, -1), (999, 1, 2, 1)" contradict each other. The last insert is with the same `tag_value` (1), but with different `user_id` (2 instead of 100). Isn't this a typo?

Comment: I'm more concerned about "PARTITION BY tag_id % 200". You might be happier if you just skip the partitioning.

Comment: Have you tried using batch inserts instead of one row at a time? Then if the batch fails, you can resend the entire batch. (In other words, the row that "cancels" the existing row and the row with new values should be inserted at the same time.)